# Checking if there is # tag in url angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to see if there is some # tags in url that i can parse like this

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe(hash => {
  if (hash !== undefined && hash !== null && hash !== "") {
    let result: any = hash.split('&').reduce(function (result: any, item: string) {
      let parts = item.split('=');
      result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
      return result;
    }, {});
});
```

I dont like that i have all those **IF** to check if there is **#**, is there some better solution to see if there is **# tag** in url like query params

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('value');
```

Because in url I have query params nad # also, is there way to check that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe(hash => {
  const hashMap = new URLSearchParams(hash);

  const value = hashMap.get('value');
});
```

I'm not entirely sure if the `fragment` observable returns the hash with a `#` prepended. If so, you should trim that first